# using @variable not working on mysql where

Tags: mysql

Good day sir..

I was trying to find transactions that are not balance..

so I tried running my query

```
select transCode,sum(debit) as debitx, sum(credit) as creditx, 
sum(credit-debit)as total 
from x_general_transactions_details 
where total != 0
 group by transCode
```

but above code doesnt work since you cannot use alias on where so I tried using a variable

```
select transCode,sum(debit) as debitx, sum(credit) as creditx, 
@total := sum(credit-debit) as total 
from x_general_transactions_details 
where @total != 0
group by transCode
```

this query doesnt give me an error but doesnt give me a result as well,
could you please pin point whats wrong with this query?

the goal of this query is just to find which @total is not equal to 0 which means its not balance..

Thank you very much and have a nice day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `HAVING` ...

```
select transCode,sum(debit) as debitx, sum(credit) as creditx, 
       sum(credit-debit)as total 
  from x_general_transactions_details 
 group by transCode
having sum(credit-debit) != 0
```